# Correct syntax for extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to follow the example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290929/Using-ASP-Net-Profile-Feature-in-a-Web-Application) to create profile feature

What is tripping me up is that my web.config also contains `group name` to group the properties. My web.config looks like this

**web.config:**

```
    <profile defaultProvider="MyCMSSqlProfileProvider" automaticSaveEnabled="false" inherits ="TestProj.Controls.wProfile">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="MyCMSSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="dbMyCMSConnectionString" applicationName="MyCMS" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"/>
            </providers>
            <properties>
                 <group name="Personal">
                    <add name="FirstName" type="String" />
                    <add name="LastName" type="String" />
                    <add name="Gender" type="String" />
                    <add name="BirthDate" type="DateTime" />
                    <add name="Occupation" type="String" />
                    <add name="Website" type="String" />
                </group>
                <group name="Address">
                    <add name="Country" type="String" />
                    <add name="Address" type="String" />
                    <add name="AptNumber" type="String" />
                    <add name="City" type="String" />
                    <add name="State" type="String" />
                    <add name="PostalCode" type="String" />
                </group>

//.....etc
```

I started to change the class named ProfileInfo to

**ProfileInfo.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestProj.controls
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Personal
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string Occupation { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Address
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string AptNumber { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    }


}
```

but know realize this isn't going to work as I need to return all group name properties  together exposed through `wProfile`

**wProfile.cs:**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Profile;
namespace Project1.Account
{
    public class wProfile : ProfileBase
    {

        public ProfileInfo ProfileInfo
        { 
            get { return (ProfileInfo) GetPropertyValue("ProfileInfo"); }       
        } 

        public static wProfile GetProfile() 
        { 
            return (wProfile) HttpContext.Current.Profile; 
        } 

        public static wProfile GetProfile(string userName) 
        { 
            return (wProfile) Create(userName); 
        }  
    }
}
```

How do I set up `ProfileInfo.cs` correctly to expose the profile off all properties including group names?

In codebehind I want to do something like this

```
        // Personal Info
        txtFirstName.Text = lprofile.Personal.FirstName;
        txtLastName.Text = lprofile.Personal.LastName;
        ddlGenders.SelectedValue = lprofile.Personal.Gender;
        if (lprofile.Personal.BirthDate != DateTime.MinValue)
            txtBirthDate.Text = lprofile.Personal.BirthDate.ToShortDateString();
        ddlOccupations.SelectedValue = lprofile.Personal.Occupation;
        txtWebsite.Text = lprofile.Personal.Website;

        // Address Info
        ddlCountries.SelectedValue = lprofile.Address.Country;
        txtAddress.Text = lprofile.Address.Address;
        txtAptNumber.Text = lprofile.Address.AptNumber;
        txtCity.Text = lprofile.Address.City;
        ddlStates1.SelectedValue = lprofile.Address.State;
        txtPostalCode.Text = lprofile.Address.PostalCode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `Personal`/`Address` as properties to your profile model i.e.

```
[Serializable]
public class Personal
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Address
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string AptNumber { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ProfileInfo
{
    public Personal Personal { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8b58y5d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Properties can be organized in the user profile as groups of
>   properties. Profile property groups are specified using the group
>   configuration element. For example, the different properties of user's
>   address information can be grouped together in an Address group. You
>   can then access the grouped properties using the group identifier and
>   the property name (for example, Profile.Address.Street or
>   Profile.Address.City).